# Invalid Layout (EditText)

Tags: android, android-layout

It says that my EditTexts are invalid.
I don't know what is wrong with it but more specific it says that android:id is invalid.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SettingsActivity">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#FF0000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Testapp" />
     <EditText
        android:id="@+id/host" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/text_view_header" 
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions" 
        android:hint="@string/host" /> 
     <EditText
        android:id="@+id/host2" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/spyhost" 
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions" 
        android:hint="@string/host2" />
     <Button
        android:id="@+id/save"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/vidhost"
        android:text="Save Settings"
        android:onClick="onClickSave" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT: The fix was really easy. There were chars that would not get displayed so replace all spaces with new spaces or tabs. The cause of this is most likely copying content from a website. Thanks at @Squonk

Comment: Your EditTexts and Buttons each have a `android:layout_below` attribute but you don't have any widgets within that `RelativeLayout` with any of the ids associated with those attributes.

Answer (score 0):

```
 android:layout_below="@+id/text_view_header"
```

should be

```
 android:layout_below="@id/text_view_header"
```

in layout_below attribute there should not be "+" sign before id.And the id of the element set in layout_below should be in the same parent layout as the element to which layout_below is set. In your code the second edittext i.e. host2 edittext has layout_below attribute in which id is spyhost, but there is no such element with spyhost id the relative layout defined. Similar problem is there with the button.